# Multiplicative group of finite field with non irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider multiplicative group $(Z_3[x]/\langle x^3+x+2\rangle)^*$

My exercise is "Show that $x+\langle x^3+x+2\rangle$ is not a generator of this group and Find a generator of this group."

But I don't know how. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* $x^3+x+2 \equiv (x+1)(x^2+2x+2) \bmod3$ implies that the group is a product of two groups. Find the order of these groups.

*Solution:*

Since $x^3+x+2 = (x+1)(x^2+2x+2) = (x+1)((x+1)^2+1)$, we have
$$
R=
\frac{F_3[x]}{\langle x^3+x+2 \rangle}
\cong
\frac{F_3[x]}{\langle x+1 \rangle}
\times
\frac{F_3[x]}{\langle (x+1)^2+1 \rangle}
\cong
F_3 \times F_3[u]
\cong
F_3 \times F_9
$$
with $u^2=-1$.

Therefore,
$
R^{\times}
\cong F_3^{\times} \times F_9^{\times}
\cong C_2 \times C_8
$ is not cyclic. In particular, $\bar x$ is not a generator.

Indeed, if you compute the powers of $\bar x$, using $\bar x^3+\bar x+2=0$, you'll find that $\bar x^8=1$.

Comment: sorry actually i don't understand but thank you i'll try it.